# Design and Development Methodologies for the single developer

Tags: design, development-methodologies, solo-development

At my work, typically the developers here all work separately, we may share projects but often only do so when another isn't working on it (for reference, we're a consulting company. So someone may work on project A one month, then three months late, I may too).

What methodologies can we use to improve the quality of the code we produce when there is typically only one developer (at most three) on the project?